# What to use instead of QuickLook.framework to handle HTML?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was using

> QuickLook.framework

to show a pdf file in the most simple way but now I need to display an HTML document instead but what it displays is plain unreadable text that starts with

> %PDF-1.3 %Äåòåë§ó ÐÄÆ 4 0 obj << /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream

So QuickLook obviously isn't a good for displaying HTML.
What can I use instead that works similarly?
Or can I adapt QuickLook to use it for HTML?

Answer (score 2):

On the iOS, the `UIWebView` can display PDF files without problems. I have done this on numerous occasions and it is very simple, you get a lot for free (scrolling, zooming, etc).

QuickLook can [not display HTML content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html).

Comment: Thanks, I know about WebViews, but here I used QuickLook for PDF and hoped I could just "replace" it or adapt for HTML, does that seem possible to You?

Comment: Are you trying to display a PDF or a HTML document? From your question it seems you want to show a PDF file.

Comment: I was using this way to show PDFs and now I am trying to adapt the same for HTMLs, possible?

Comment: In the example in your question the Quicklook view clearly contains the PDF displayed as text (as can be seen by the `%PDF` magic header). Can you please post some example code?

Comment: It says that when I direct it to an HTML, otherwise it just shows the PDF, am I doing something wrong here? Does it somehow expect the HTML to be .PDF so does this instead?  
Can't, updated to 10.8 ML, new Xcode is still downloading :/

Comment: Sounds like your web server outputs HTML MIME type for a PDF document then. Did you expect a PDF to show, or HTML content? Again, you are clearly getting a PDF from the server.